# jQuery compare inputvalue with span objects

Tags: jquery

I've built a little game and everything works sofar, except the limitation of the user entering a number twice.

User enter a number;

```
<form>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Guess" />
</form> 

var guess = $input.val();
```

The numbers(guesses) are sorted and stored in a span with id guesses.

```
    $guesses.append('<span class="guess ' + responseClass + '">' + guess + " " +     '</span> ');
    var sorted = $.makeArray($('#guesses span')).sort(function(a, b) {
        return (parseInt($(a).text()) < parseInt($(b).text())) ? -1 : 1;
    });
$('#guesses').html(sorted);
```

How can I compare inputvalue(guess) with the numbers stored in #guesses? Lets say I enter 50, and then 50 again - I want my program to tell me "already entered number" or something likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main storage place for guesses should not be the `span`, but a `guesses` variable. It’s okay to have the `span` on the page, but it should be updated only to synchronize with the `guesses` variable. This is because variables are meant to be general-purpose data holders, so you can easily manipulate them in many ways, but `span`s are only mean to store HTML elements to display to the user, so it is harder to do other things with them.

In this case, the `guesses` variable could be an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You would initialize it with `var guesses = [];`. To add a guess and keep `guesses` sorted:

```js
guesses.push(guess);
guesses.sort();
redisplayGuesses(guesses); // if you actually want this

function redisplayGuesses(guesses) {
    $guessesOnPage = $('#guesses');
    // overwrite all previous guesses on the page, to make synchronization simple
    $guessesOnPage.empty(); // remove guess elements
    guesses.forEach(function(guess) {
        $guessesOnPage.append($("<span class=" + responseClass + ">" + guess + "</span>"));
    });
}
```

This uses [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to modify the array. `redisplayGuesses` uses [`.empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove existing child elements and then [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)s them again in a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

And for what you asked, how to tell if a guess has already been guessed:

```js
if (guesses.indexOf(guess) === -1) {
    // guess not found
    processNewGuess(guess);
} else {
    // the guess was found in `guesses`
    alert("You already guessed this. Guess a different number.");
}
```

This uses the method [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which is possible to use on `Array`s, but not `span`s.

Comment: Seems like what Im after, gonna test this. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm - now my game is performing as wanted. Thanks alot for the help and tips Rory!